# How do I dynamically access elements of a particular Div tag?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, getelementsbytagname

This is my JavaScript's `onMouseOver` event handler for Div tags. (It works fine, in at least Chrome and IE):

```
function changeCallout(sender, e) {
    document.getElementById(sender.id).className = "callout2";
}
```

What I would like to be able to do is to set the color property of the H2 tag contained within the Div that is having it's class changed.

I know I should be able to access either the color property or change the class, but I'm not able to figure out how to access only the appropriate H2 tag (I'm aware of `getElementsByTagName`). What's the syntax to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the wanted `h2` is the first one under the target `div`, then use the following to search relative to that `div`:

```
var div = document.getElementById(sender.id);
var h2 = div.getElementsByTagName("h2")[0];
```

If it's not the first one, simply change `0` to `n` (on the second line) where `n` is the position of the desired header.

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementById(sender.id).getElementsByTagName('h2')` will return a NodeList of all the H2 elements inside the element with the given id.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, getElementsByTagName will do the trick, but remember that it also gets nested elements. For example, if you have a div within a div with h2 elements, those will get dumped in the array as well.

I know this wasn't your question, but you don't need to get the sender element's id to use it in code; just use the this keyword as the argument, and the element will be passed in to the function. It works in both inline html elements and eventListener calls, and you won't need to use getElementById.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style>
            div {width:100px;height:100px;background-color:#F00;}
            </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div onclick="onClick(this)">I'm a div</div>

        <script>
            function onClick(div) {
                alert(div.innerHTML);
            }
            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey. I'll have to remember this.